# Maps between manifolds with boundary and homeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Assume we have $f:(M,\partial M)\rightarrow (N,\partial N)$ connected 3-manifolds, not compact, such that $f$ is an homeomorphism onto its image and $f(\partial M)=\partial N$. Can say that $f$ has to be surjective?

Comment: You are missing the assumption that M is compact (or that f is proper). Then the answer is positive. And it works in all dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Take $M=N=[0,\infty)$ and take any continuous injection 
$$f : M=[0,\infty) \to [0,1) \subset [0,\infty) = N
$$
such that $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, let the boundaries be empty, and assume that $M$ is a ball. Then this does not hold. If you want boundaries, you can make multiple components, but one component (of both $M$ and $N$) without a boundary and repeat this trick.

If you are not satisfied by this, you can take $N$ with a non-trivial boundary and remove an closed ball $B$. Then $M=N-B$ is a manifold that is clearly embedded in $N$ and is surjective on the boundary.

Comment: You counterxamples are clear but I was looking when the manifolds are connected and by $f:(M,\partial M)\rightarrow (N,\partial N)$ I meant that the boundary went to the boundary so that basically $f(\partial M)=\partial N$ which I added in the question now.

Comment: Yes, that is why i've added another counterexample.